# Matlab code to eliminate points outside a surface

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have these two images -matrix (links) analyzed with my code. 
I would like to delete all the points outside the "circle" of the image  so it's possible to see better the surface.

Being a Matrix, i thought to delete all the values outside putting them to zero, but how can i do that? As you could see the surface is not a very circle..can you help me please?
[image: http://i41.tinypic.com/23qxq9.png]
[image: http://i43.tinypic.com/2cegs8z.png]

Thank you

Comment: Actually it seems more like an ellipse …

Comment: Values outside circle seem higher than withing a circle. If this is the case, than just simple thresholding should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `imfindcircles` from the Image Processing Toolbox.